# What should be the correct format of data in Morris.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, morris.js

I want to draw Morris.js chart with PHP & Mysql. There are no errors and warnings when i am opening the php file with chrome but still the morris chart is not displaying. I assume that the problem is with my data inside morris.

Any help will be very useful.

```
            $a= $row2['dateofassign'];
            $d= $row2['t_deadline'];
            $c= $row2['comp_date'];
            $n= $name['w_name'];
            $i= $name['w_id'];

            $chart_data .= "{ AssignDate:'".$a."', TaskDeadline:".$d.", 
            TaskCompletionDate:".$c.", worker:".$n."}, ";
```

I think that $char_data value is not properly formatted

```
        <script>
        Morris.Bar({
        element : 'chart',
        data:
           [<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
           xkey:'worker',
           ykeys:['AssignDate', 'TaskDeadline', 'TaskCompletionDate'],
           labels:['Assign Date', 'Deadline', 'Completion Date'],
           hideHover:'auto'
         });
        </script>
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: No there was no error. I even changed my code and displayed the result via html table and it worked well.